# How to find query that populated a marketing cloud data extention?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I am looking at a data extension that is appended to daily. Is there an easy way to find the query that is adding that data? There are too many folders for me to dig through to find the query with the right target data-extension. I am looking for something like a history log for a data extension.

Answer (score 3):

You can do an API RetrieveRequest to get the query definition name, etc. using the [QueryDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/querydefinition.htm) Object in the SOAP API. You would filter based off the `DataExtensionTarget.Name` property.

```
  <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>QueryDefinition</ObjectType>
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
        <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>DataExtensionTarget.Name</Properties>
        <Properties>DataExtensionTarget.CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>CategoryID</Properties>
        <Filter xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="q1:SimpleFilterPart">
           <q1:Property>DataExtensionTarget.Name</q1:Property>
           <q1:SimpleOperator>equals</q1:SimpleOperator>
           <q1:Value>4_bullseye_mathprep</q1:Value>
        </Filter>
     </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

This will return all Queries that have a target of that specific DE. CategoryID is the unique ID used by SFMC to define which folder the definition is in.

Answer (score 1):

You can access `Automation Studio > Activities Tab`.

[image: Activities]

On left menu select `All SQL Query` then type on `Search SQL Query` input field the data extension name.
Should return queries that have a target data extension with that name.

Example:

[image]