# How to search through all queries in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, source

We have tons of queries in our Marketing Cloud org, and we would like to know which queries use a specific field (because something is going to happen with that field).

For Sales Cloud this is easy: I have Visual Studio Code with all Apex sources and searching is easy. I am not aware of such a solution for Marketing Cloud.

It does not have to be Visual Studio Code per se, it might also be a primitive download/export functionality of the query sources.

Comment: maybe this helps? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/382999/find-all-sql-query-activities-which-contain-specific-dataextension-in-query/383036#383036

Comment: @JonasLamberty The question is about the same as the one I have, I recognize that. But the answers are not so simple or even complete. I have added some remarks to the answers there, because as they are now, I do not know how to apply them.

Comment: If you reframe your question to be different than that existing question, then this can likely be re-opened. As it stands, what you are asking has been answered in the previous post.